# What is the Use of SocketFlags.Partial?

Tags: c#, sockets

I am creating a socket server and I was wondering what
the difference is between SocketFlags.Partial and SocketFlags.None

I have searched for the meaning. But it was not clear

> **Partial**
>
> Partial send or receive for message,

so what is the difference between the following pieces of code

```
 _buffer = new byte[2];
 _socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallbackStatic), null);


_buffer = new byte[2];
_socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.Partial, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallbackStatic), null);
```

Thanks

Comment: I believe it's identical to the Win32 `MSG_PARTIAL` option, that you can read about [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741686(v=vs.85).aspx). I think in most normal usage, you should just ignore its existence and if you're doing TCP, it won't have any effect anyway.

Comment: Quote: _The lpFlags parameter is both an input and an output parameter, allowing applications to sense the output state of the MSG_PARTIAL flag bit. Be aware that the MSG_PARTIAL flag bit is not supported by all protocols._ So I think it doesn't do anything here.

Comment: so it is the same as SocketFlags.None